# Language translation by reading .txt file and print out a translated sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a Python program to translate from English to Aboriginal language which reads from `dictionary.txt` file.

That program should contain pairs of English and translated words separated by a comma (,) and builds a dictionary with them. Program should then read in lines of text from the user (until a blank line) and print out a translated sentence, where each word has been looked up in the dictionary.

`dictionary.txt` file looks like following:

```
afternoon,wuraji-wuraji
I,ngaju
bird,jirripirdi
like,kuja-piya
dance,juka-pinyi
python,malilyi
laugh,ngarlarrimi
we,ngalipa
```

My  program should work like this:

```
English: I like python
ngaju kuja-piya malilyi
English: we laugh
ngalipa ngarlarrimi
English:
```

I am so far able to make a program which produces translation for individual words but not the combined sentences. I am just wondering how can I do that?

My code is like following:

```
user_input = []
translate = {}
for line in open('dictionary.txt'):
        english, aboriginal = line.split(',')
        translate[english] = aboriginal

while user_input != "":
  user_input = input("English: ")
  if user_input == "":
    break
  else:
    print(translate[user_input])
```

Comment: Look up `.split(" ")` ( you can omit the " ") to split up your input and translate each seperate word. `List comprehensions` might get handy as well - look up that as well. If they are too complicated, experiment with `for someWord in user_input.split():\n    print(someWord)` ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @JeanRostan for your help, I was able to output correct output with the following code (even though it is very primitive one):

```
user_input = []
translate = {}
for line in open('dictionary.txt'):
        english, aboriginal = line.split(',')
        translate[english] = aboriginal

while user_input != "":
  user_input = input("English: ")
  if user_input == "":
    break
  else:
    tempList = []
    for word in user_input.split():
        tempList.append(translate[word])
    A = ("".join(tempList))
    B = (A.replace('\n',' ')) 
    B = B.rstrip()
    print(B)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write `translate[user_input]`, you're just accessing the key `user_input` in your dictionary, but if it's a whole sentence, you won't find it of course.
So you need to loop and find each word translation, then making the sentence.

```
user_input = []
translate = {}
for line in open('dictionary.txt'):
        english, aboriginal = line.split(',')
        translate[english] = aboriginal

while user_input != "":
  user_input = input("English: ")
  if user_input == "":
    break
  else:
    tempList = []
    for word in user_input.split():
        tempList.append(translate[word])
    print(" ".join(tempList))
```

Comment: thank you for your help, I was able to find correct code with little modification / addition to your code.